# PaperProps in MUI doesn't understand breakpoints such as xs: , md: and etc

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
 <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
        PaperProps={{
          style: {
            margin: 0,
            width: '100%',
            minHeight: {xs: '100%', md:'0%'},
            maxWidth: 800,
            backgroundColor: "#2c3059",
    
          },
        }} />
```

I am trying to change minHeight on different screen-size but the break points such as {xs: '100%', md:'0%'} Doesn't work at all, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use MUI version 5: replace "style" with sx prop

```
  PaperProps={{
       sx: {
         margin: 0,
         width: '100%',
         minHeight: {xs: '100%', md:'0%'},
         maxWidth: 800,
         backgroundColor: "#2c3059",
      }
}}
```

Comment: oh god brother you save my day